# Dom-repeat not re-rendering when Array sorts

Tags: polymer-2.x

**I have an array property:**

```
arrayList: {
    type: Array,
    value:[
              {id:"1",candy:"Reeces"},
              {id:"1",candy:"M&M"},
              {id:"1",candy:"KitKat"},
              {id:"1",candy:"Twizzlers"}
          ]
}
```

**and a boolean property**

```
forceRerender: {
    type: Boolean,
    value: false
}
```

**I call them in a Dom-Repeat to populate the HTML:**

```
<template is="dom-repeat" as="candy" items="[[getCandyList(arrayList, forceRerender)]]">
    <div id="[[candy.id]]" class="candy-row" data="[[candy]]" on-tap="selectCandy">
</template>
```

**The `selectCandy()` function looks like this:**

```
selectCandy(event) {
    let arr = this.arrayList;
    for(let j = 0, i = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if(arr[j].select) {
            let temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
            i++;
        }
    }
    this.set('forceRerender', !this.forceRerender);
}
```

**And my getter:**

```
getCandyList(arr,forceRerender) {
    return arr;
}
```

My `selectCandy()` effectively rearranges the `arrayList`, but does not visually update the HTML content to represent this. I can't seem to figure out why.

I've made a separate array and used that to change values. I've made a local array and pushed to that and returned it. I've rewritten the order in which things are done. Separated the sections up multiple times to review each portion individually.

I've been at this for at least 3 hours and I'm lost. Can't anyone explain to me here what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the solution:

```
getCandyList(arr,forceRerender) {
    let rowList = [];
    for(let j = 0, i = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if(arr[j].select) {
            let temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
            i++;
        }
    }
    arr.forEach(function(object) {
        rowList.push(object);
    }.bind(this));
    return rowList;
}
```

and

```
selectCandy(event) {
    this.set('forceRerender', !this.forceRerender);
}
```

moral of the story here is do all the stuff you wanna do to your objects and arrays in the get function.

Answer (score 1):

This below example could give you some inspiration. As far as I understood, you want to move up (top) the selected item.

[Demo](https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/LaNzQG?editors=1010)

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[getCandyList(arrayList, forceRerender)]]" as="candy">
    <paper-item on-tap="selectCandy"> <div id="[[candy.id]]" class="candy-row" data="[[candy]]"> [[candy.id]] - [[candy.candy]]</div>   
    </paper-item>
</template>
```

And the Js may look like:

```
selectCandy(e) {
      let temp = this.arrayList;
      //In order to observable change in dom-repeat
      this.set('arrayList', []); 
      temp.splice(e.model.index, 1);
      temp.unshift(e.model.candy); 
      this.set("arrayList",  temp);

      this.set('forceRerender', !this.forceRerender);
}
```

You may re-organize the array with other types.